# Имя массива из переменных

Tags: php

Как из нескольких переменных (их значений) составить имя массива?

Например есть три переменные:

```
$peremannaya_1 = "a";
$peremannaya_2 = "b";
$peremannaya_3 = "c";
```

Из их значений необходимо составить массив с именем:

```
$abc = ($data_1, $data_2, $data_3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот статья из мануала http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php

И сообственно пример

```
$peremannaya_1 = "a";
$peremannaya_2 = "b";
$peremannaya_3 = "c";
$data_1="d1";
$data_2="d2";
$data_3="d3";

$ar_name= $peremannaya_1.$peremannaya_2.$peremannaya_3;
$$ar_name= array ($data_1, $data_2, $data_3);
print_r ($abc);
```

Можно и так

```
$ar_name= $peremannaya_1.$peremannaya_2.$peremannaya_3;
$abc= array ($data_1, $data_2, $data_3);
print_r ($$ar_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS[$peremannaya_1.$peremannaya_2.$peremannaya_3] = [];
var_dump($GLOBALS['abc']);
```

или так

```
${$peremannaya_1.$peremannaya_2.$peremannaya_3} = [];
var_dump($abc);
```